# AngularJS directive for jQuery UI datePicker does not hide calendar when scrolling

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am writing an AngularJS directive for jQuery UI datepicker. I would like to hide the drop down calendar when scrolling, but right now I am not able to get it to hide.You can visit my plunker here to see it.
https://plnkr.co/edit/CuJB1vsKuaqfkh8NFUXb?p=preview

My directive is below:

```
module.directive('myDatePicker', ['$window', '$timeout',
  function($window, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: "ngModel",
      link: linkFunc
    };
  }
]);

function linkFunc(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
  var updateModel = function(dateText) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);

    });
  };
  var options = {
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      updateModel(dateText);
    },
    hideOnInputClick: true,
    maxDate: "+0d",
    selectOtherMonths: true
  };
  element.datepicker(options);
  var body = element.find('body');

  body.bind('scroll', function() {
    element.find('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
    scope.apply();
  });
}
```

Would anyone know why this happens and how to get the calendar to hide?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
element.parent().parent().on('scroll', function() {
   element.datepicker('hide'),
   scope.$apply();
 // --^ bad idea, this will trigger a lot while scrolling. debounce the handler
});
```

See updated [**plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/RGmYhOht9sgsN7vc4uG9?p=preview).

Your original code doesn't work because scroll is happening on a `<div>`, not `<body>`. Even if body was scrolling your event handler won't work since `body`, `#ui-datepicker-div` etc are outside your datepicker element and `find()` won't work.

Comment: for the debounce. using $timeout() should work right?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  // do what ever you want
});
```

Comment: nop. I tried both element.datepicker('hide'), $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide(); not working. need the exact method to hide the drop down calendar